# HTML Select: set default to given value, not from list of options

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

so I realize that you can do

```
<select>
    <option value="true">True</option>
    <option value="false" selected >False</option>
</select>
```

to choose what you want.

But in my case, I am using React, and it looks like this:

```
<select>
    {this.renderList()}
</select>
```

so I don't have access to the options.
What I do have is the value of the option I want as the default.
I am trying to show the default value and allow the user to change it.

Is there a way to use an attirbute to use this value and set the default as that?

What I would like:

```
<select default={this.props.user.profile.item}>
    {this.renderList()}
</select>
```

As far as attributes go, I tried placeholder(no effect), defaultValue(no effect), and value(displays, but cannot change).

Comment: try  `<select value={this.props.user.profile.item}>`

Answer (score 2):

You can set a default option in a drop-down list by using the `value` attribute for the `<select>` tag. That is, you can do it as below

```
<select value={this.props.user.profile.item}>
    {this.renderList()}
</select>
```

Please read more about it in the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html)

**UPDATE**

You can also set the default value as below. Try that..

```
<select defaultValue={this.props.user.profile.item}>
    {this.renderList()}
</select>
```

Check [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#default-value) for more details..

Comment: Hi, Lal, I've already tried doing it that way, but the problem is that I can't change to another option. This dropdown belongs in a changeInfo section and I intend to show the already-set info, then allow the user to change to another option is need be. Thank you.

Comment: @ys27 If you want an "uncontrolled input" then use `defaultValue`.

Comment: Hi, as I've mentioned in the post, I've tried those already, but they will not work. DefaultValue only loads once initially and the data {this.props.user.profile.item} is not available that early and will not load. Are there any options other than value, defaultValue, and placeholder? Thanks.

Comment: @ys27 You didn't mention the timing problem in your post, in fact I would go so far as to say this answer *is* the correct answer to your question, but your problem is a different question you have asked in this comment.

Comment: @Aaron What should I add in the question to make it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use componentDidMount() method and change value of select Dom element to default value.

Answer (score 0):

This solution provides as a solution to the problem, but there are problems such as refreshing screwing up the DOM, and the value not being set properly when refreshed. Everything works perfectly well without refresh.

On the select, I use value and onChange.

ex)

```
<select onChange={this.changeItem} value= 
              {this.props.user.profile.item}
              ref="item">
    {this.renderItems()}
</select>
```

separately, the function changeItem:

```
changeItem() {
    this.setState({
        item: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.item).value
     });
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. This code will *not* allow `<select>` to be changed. Presumably you handle `state.item` somewhere to update `user.profile.item`?

Comment: I'm not sure. I thought that by using setState inside changeItem, the value would be allowed to be changed, and it was what happened. user.profile.item is only changed at the end when the form is submitted (from db)

Answer (score 0):

Lal already answered your question by pointing out `value` and `defaultValue`, but then you added this comment:

> DefaultValue only loads once initially and the data
>   {this.props.user.profile.item} is not available that early and will
>   not load.

So if I understand: you have no initial value, you want to update the value from props when it changes, but allow the user to change the value afterwards independent of the original value. In this case you should use [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops):

> Use this as an opportunity to react to a prop transition before
>   `render()` is called by updating the state using `this.setState()`.
>   The old props can be accessed via `this.props`. Calling
>   this.setState() within this function will not trigger an additional
>   render.

Example:

```
componentWillReceieveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.state.item != nextProps.user.profile.item) {
        this.setState({item: nextProps.user.profile.item});
    }
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({item: event.currentTarget.value});
}

<select value={this.state.item} onChange={this.handleChange}>
    {this.renderItems()}
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, what Lal showed me was what I've already tried, but I guess I didn't make it clear. So I DO have an initial value, and that is what I've set originally, and yes I do want to update the value when it is changed by the user, whether or not it's using props. I've come back to this problem, because the values changed in setState are previous values. I will try the componentWillReceiveProps. Thank you.

Comment: I don't quite understand the part nextProps.user.profile.item. Why would changing the state trigger componentWillReceiveProps in the first place??